# Moving users from drupal DB to EE Database

Tags: users, password, forgot-password

I am in need of moving some content from Drupal site to EE site. Problem is that this content includes User accounts and passwords. Is there any way of swapping the hashing functions in EE for the one that drupal is using? So I dont need to manipulate the hashes alone nor ask all users to reset passwords?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep old Drupal members database and create a custom extension that will be triggered when user tries to log in for the first time (password in EE not set). It will utilize Drupal authenticate functions to check whether the user is permitted to log in and it yes - set password in EE database and log him in.